# Failed to load resource sencha microloader

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have uploaded my sencha project to my server.I am just loading an external HTML file in my app. I am getting this error on running the app

```
GET http://myserverurl/sencha/knolV/.sencha/app/microloader/development.js 403 (Forbidden)
```

It works when i run it using Cordova on Android but its not working when i uploaded it on the server. I have changed the permissions of the complete app to 777 also.

The code that i am using for loading the HTML page

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
config: {
    id: 'MyPanel',
    itemId: 'MyPanel',
    scrollable: true,
    listeners: [
        {
            fn: 'onMyPanelActivate',
            event: 'activate'
        }
    ]
},    onMyPanelActivate: function(newActiveItem, container, oldActiveItem, eOpts) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        //local path of your html file
        url: 'http://some-link/story.html',
        success : function(response) {
           Ext.getCmp('MyPanel').setHtml(response.responseText);
        },
        failure : function(response) {  
            var text = response.responseText;
            Ext.Msg.alert('Error', text, Ext.emptyFn);            }
    });
}});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know why development.js was forbidden, but i changed the path in index.html to projectFolder/touch/microloder/development.js .Now it works.